# How to know which Database.SaveResult instance corresponds to my SObject

Tags: apex, dml, database

I am currently trying to Update and Insert to collections of SObjects.

I perform the actions(update&insert) separately, obtaining a Database.SaveResult Array as feedback.

The problem is that I can't find out in an error scenario, which was the error that failed the Update/Insert of a certain SObject.

For example, I can easily determine if a record was Updated or Inserted successfully, by:
1. Iterating Dabase.SaveResult []

1.1- Checking if isSuccess?
 - Yes: Read the id of the record
 - Write some feedback info on it
 - No(is an error): 
   *How to derive here from a SaveResult instance, which SObject failed to update/insert?*

Thank you!
E.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the SaveResult[] array matches the order of the inserted array.

```
List<Thing__c> myThings = new List<Thing__c>();

//... 

Database.SaveResult[] saveResults = Database.insert(myThings, false);

for (integer x=0; x<myThings.size(); x++) {
    //saveResults[x] is the saveResult of insert myThings[x]
}
```